# How would a use case in health care look like, compared to the financial side of IOTA?

Tags: data

As I only know the financial side of IOTA, I wonder how would a use case looks like in the health care world. For example if a user wants to share his health care data to different doctors. Is it like the user has the seed and every health care data (for example heart rate) was previously sent to a different address of his seed. And as the user wants to share these data he has to tell the doctor the addresses where he can find them? Or is it completely different to the financial side of IOTA?

Comment: This seems rather speculative, it would be great if you could be more specific. Currently this mainly asks for guesses.

Answer (score -2):

I would not think in this scenarios with the limited tools IOTA provide today (handly managing our seeds, for instance). The value here is in being able to propagate anonymouysly our health data, maybe get paid for it, while we allow data analysis and research that could lead to find patterns and, therefore, diagnostics.

The way I see it, our medical info will be hosted in the Tangle (MAM allows this already). Each time you visit your doctor you will be able to decide whether you wanna broadcast the info to place it in some kind of data market.

This is not only awesome in terms of having medical histories digitalized with inmutability granted. It's about what all that information could teach researchers once is put together.